# Jump to another existing session (using PHP's default session handler)

Tags: php, session

I have a scenario like this:

`UserJoe has session_id abc123` abc123 is stored in UserJoe's row in the users table in the DB.

`UserJoe calls AdminBob and reports a problem.`

`AdminBob needs to experience UserJoe's problem first hand`

So, I'd like to do something like:

```
01|  $sessionId = getSessionId("UserJoe");
02|  changeToExistingSession($sessionId);
03|  if($_SESSION["name"] == "UserJoe") echo "successfully changed users";
```

Line 02 is where I'm kinda stuck... Any ideas?

(preferably not using `session_save_path()` anywhere :P)

EDIT: And it's just for the duration of the page execution. I'd like to keep AdminBob's session cookie intact.

Comment: depending on the authentication system you don't need their exact session, you just need to set the session var(s) used to id a person (say user id)

Comment: Yeah.. but I've got certain session vars that are only stored serialized in a user's session file. Things that are only used once or twice. I *really* need to imitate their session. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you store `UserJoe`'s session ID in a database together with the report, then I think you can use `session_id()` to set `AdminBob`'s session ID to `UserJoe`'s session id.

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET["id"]))
  {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["foobar"] = $_GET["bar"];
    echo "Setting...";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
  }
  else
  {
    session_id($_GET["id"]);
    var_dump($_GET["id"]);
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
  }
?>
```

To test: Open this page in one browser and set `bar` to anything.

```
index.php?bar=blahblahblah
```

Open a new browser and visit the same page but do not set `bar`, get the value of `PHPSESSID` and set it as `id`'s value

```
index.php?id=[value of PHPSESSID]
```

You should see the other browser's session in the newly opened browser

Comment: Thanks! Let me give that a quick whirl. I'll let you know what I get.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I tried this: `function changeToExistingSession($sess_id){session_id($sess_id);session_start();}`

Comment: This is what I got: http://pastebin.com/nZjv39TG perhaps it's a configuration thing... *googling*

Comment: Hmmm.. Is there another `session_start()` at the top of the file? I assume there is since you need to log `AdminBob` in right? If so, use `session_write_close()` before `session_id($_GET["id"])`

Comment: looks like session.auto_start = true was getting in the way. your solution worked like a charm! thanks!

Comment: But please be aware of various session hijacking and session fixation, especially in your app where setting session id is allowed